# is there any hook in wp woo-commerce plugin to enable the .js file instead of min.js?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to load the checkout.js file of the woo-commerce plugin instead of the checkout.min.js, I am modifying the same function. I need to load the modified js.

I know it is possible to use the 
`wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-checkout' );`

But is there any filter to load the '.js' instead of 'min.js'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is not exactly what you are  asking for but you can add in your wp-config.php

```
define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

It debugging constant that apply to use not minified versions for all js files.

Comment: WooCommerce is checking the SCRIPT_DEBUG constant before registering all javascript(.js) file. If it is true, then it will register an un-minified file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, we need to "wp_dequeue_script" for the checkout.min.js and enqueue the script from the theme folder.

My requirement is to load the checkout.js instead of checkout.min.js. Because we can't able to modify the min.js file.

Answer (score -1):

I just saved current checkout.min.js and then copied checkout.js over it. I was also editing this file, adding some debugging. Once finished, just restored original minified file

Comment: This is a comment i guess, not a answer